# How to switch the right side of the Jsplite between blank/JTabbedPane

Tags: java

I have a Jsplitpane where on the left side  I show a list and on the right side there is JTabbedPane. If I click on a list item,  then the JTabbedPane will update the info. Everything works good.

Now my question is, when no list item is clicked on ( so basically when you run it first time), then I want to to replace the JTabbedPane with empty panel (blank right side). I tried to do setVisibility to be off on the JtabbedPane but then the divider is pushed all the way to the right. Is there a quick way to just make this JtabbedPane blank and then somehow make it appear later on. Here are screenshots to better explain the situation:

Fully functional window
[image: Fully functional window]

What I want when no item is clicked
[image: What I want when no item is clicked]

What happens if no item is clicked
[image: What happens if no item is clicked]

Comment: If you can post some code, it would be helpful. For now I just can say, add another component there (Like a `JPanel`), then after clicked, remove the `JPanel` and add your `JTabbedPane`.

Comment: Hmm good suggestion, I didn't put code because it is a lot of code and I thought I i would explain it with screenshots. I thought maybe there is a way  to switch views or set color filter or something